# Unable to install proftp or pureftp on centos 6 (typical instructions don't work)

Tags: centos, proftpd, pure-ftpd

I am having difficulty installing [proftp](http://www.proftpd.org/) or [pureftp](https://www.pureftpd.org/) on centos 6. I have followed the [typical instructions](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-proftpd-on-centos-6/) ([alternatively](http://www.lifelinux.com/how-to-install-pure-ftpd-on-centos-6-via-yum/)) which go like this

```
# Add EPL repository
rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

# Install
yum install proftpd

# Alternatively
yum install pure-ftpd
```

The result is the same

```
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * extras: mirrors.clouvider.net
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
No package proftpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Or as the case may be

```
No package pure-ftpd available.
```

Comment: Looks like probably epel on your machine is not enabled. Even though you installed it, you may have to enable it manually. Check `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and set it to `enabled=1` if it's not already.

Comment: Odd. I get `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo: No such file or directory`. Actually `epel.repo` is in `/etc/yum.repos.d/archive`.

Comment: move the file to `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and retry

Comment: Great success! BTW, do you know why stuff gets moved to archive?

Comment: not sure, probably just this is how the package is installed by default on your system.

Comment: Ok. Can you create a proper answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like probably `epel` on your machine is not enabled.

Even though you installed it, you may have to enable it manually.

Check `/etc/yum.repos.d/` for `epel.repo` file and set it to `enabled=1` if it's not already.

As per your finding, check also `/etc/yum.repos.d/archive`, as the file may be put there by the package installation.